# How to align label from the same starting point in Swt Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have created 2 labels with the exact same composite and same layoutData. I want my labels to be seen towards the end of the screen and also the starting letter of both the labels should begin from the same point.

```
Label l1 = new Label(composite, SWT.None);
l1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER,false, false));
l1.setText("Unmapped");

Label l2 = new Label(composite, SWT.None);
l2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER,false, false));
l2.setText("Mapped");
```

Right now, with the above code I do get my output towards the right end of the screen but the starting letters of the both the labels are at 2 different positions and not from the same starting position.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Put the labels inside another composite. This composite is aligned to the end of its parent, and the labels are at the beginning of their parent:

```
Composite labelComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
labelComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
labelComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

Label l1 = new Label(labelComposite, SWT.LEAD);
l1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
l1.setText("Unmapped");

Label l2 = new Label(labelComposite, SWT.LEAD);
l2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
l2.setText("Mapped");
```